# Test for jQuery-DataTables API object

Tags: datatables

I'm working with a mix of legacy code that uses the jQuery DataTables plugin (version 1.10.  Some of the old code passes around jQuery object, and some of the old code passes around [DataTables API objects](https://datatables.net/reference/api/).  I'd like to make all new code accept either a jQuery object or a DataTables API object, but I haven't been able to detect when a variable refers to a DataTables API object.

The only detection method I could find in the API, [isDataTable](https://datatables.net/reference/api/%24.fn.dataTable.isDataTable()), is not suitable - it take a string selector for a table and returns whether the selection has been turned into a DataTable.

The "class detection" methods in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1249554/776723) don't work; `typeof` returns `"object"`, `constructor.name` returns `"Object"`, and I don't know of a constructor to use for `instanceof` or `isPrototypeOf`.

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1250766/776723) (to same question), `Object.prototype.toString.call(var)` returns `"[object Object]"`

In Chrome, `console.log(var)` produces a summary that looks like it has some other class information:

```
▶ _Api {context: Array[1], selector: Object, ajax: Object}
```

I imagine that means there is something I could use somewhere but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27085257/776723) about where Chrome gets that name has no useful answers.

**How can I detect when a variable refers to a jQuery-DataTables API object?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dig around more by using a breakpoint in Chrome.  If you set a breakpoint just after a DataTable variable, and evaluate the variable, you'll get a complete map.  I did that, and found this:

```
var myDataTable = $('#myTable').DataTable(myOptions); 
alert(myDataTable.$.__dt_wrapper);
```

The alert returns true.  (`myOptions` is an object containing all the options for the DataTable.)  So, I looked at an object (I used `myOptions`) to see what I could test for.  You can't test directly for whether `myOptions.$.__dt_wrapper`) is false, because `myOptions.$` evaluates to `undefined`.  So:

```
if(undefined != myObjectVariable.$ && myObjectVariable.$.__dt_wrapper) {
    alert('A DataTable Object')
} else {
    alert('Not a DataTable Object')
}
```

Googling "__dt_wrapper" doesn't show any links that are unrelated to DataTables.  Looking at datatables.js, it occurs twice.  Both cases suggest that it's an internal attribute used to denote a DataTable object, or more specifically whether an object is a DataTable wrapper.

Since this is undocumented there's no guarantee that it will work in all future versions of DataTables.  But this works in DataTables 1.10.11.

Edit: I asked about this on the DataTables forum ([link](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/97055#Comment_97055)), and there indeed is a cleaner way to do this:

```
myObjectVariable instanceof $.fn.DataTable.Api
```

Is true if the object is a DataTable.  (This also works for the lower case `dataTable` object.)

Comment: "!+" is a syntax error, I'm assuming that's a typo for "!="

Comment: Turns out I'm using DataTables 1.10.3, and this solution works.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  Pleased to hear it, but I'm going to post this question on the DataTables forum and see if Allan Jardine has a better way to handle it.  I'm concerned that this might break somewhere down the line.  Yes, that's a syntax error, my bad.  I'll fix it, thanks.  Stupid shift key.

Comment: I posted a question about this [here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/36611/using-dt-wrapper-to-determine-if-an-object-is-a-datatable-object-fragile?new=1) on the DataTables forum.

Comment: @Polyergic Allan Jardine posted an improvement to my answer.